# How to add multiple featured image in meta box in post editor?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, metabox, post-thumbnails, post-meta

I would like to add multiple featured image in meta box in post editor area apart from default available featured image.

I have added the meta box but i have no idea on adding the featured image functionality.

```
function another_image_custom_meta() {
    add_meta_box('another_meta', __('Another Image'), 'another_image_callback', 'another','side');
}

add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'another_image_custom_meta');
```

Where another in fourth field is my custom post type.

```
function another_image_callback($post) {
    wp_nonce_field(basename(__FILE__), 'another_nonce');
    $p_stored_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID);
    ?>

    <p>
       Another featured image
    </p>

    <?php
}
```

Above functions works fine it show the meta box.

How can i add the link with image upload and save it as featured image to the corresponding post. Like default featured image i want the same function here. can anyone help?

Comment: You want any solution (i.e. plugin) or only info on how to implement it by yourself?

Comment: Hey check this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/45864/42701
 see if this helps you

Comment: No need any plugin.I already found multi post thumbnail does this.But i can't study the code there.so i want to Implement by myself so that i can learn each thing.If it is a easy learn guide that would be great. Thanks @ Krzysiek Dróżdż

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking for own implementation not any plugins @user42701

Comment: I'm new to coding so i lack in understanding and reading code.That is why asking help here. Thanks @helgatheviking

Comment: @sun The plugin makes this really simple. There's no need to re-invent the wheel. :)

Comment: I am also looking for a way to do this without a plugin, since I am trying to write my own plugin that does it. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: for anyone looking for this also, this might help: https://www.skyverge.com/blog/custom-post-type-with-image-uploads/

Answer (score 3):

I know you said you were looking for your own implementation, but the easiest way to add multiple featured image metaboxes is with the [Multiple Post Thumbnail plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-post-thumbnails/).

Following the plugin's documentation, the way to define a secondary box is to add this code to your theme's functions.php

```
   if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) {
        new MultiPostThumbnails(
            array(
                'label' => 'Secondary Image',
                'id' => 'secondary-image',
                'post_type' => 'post'
            )
        );
    }
```

and then to display the image in your theme somewhere:

```
if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) : MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail(get_post_type(), 'secondary-image'); endif;
```

Comment: Thanks for your time +1. I don't want to use another plugin.Need default WordPress way:)

Comment: To learn how to do it yourself is one thing, but not using a plugin, just to "not use a plugin" is silly. There's nothing wrong with using plugins to simplify our lives. If by "the default WordPress way" you mean add and save metabox data, that is exactly what the plugin does.

Comment: Plenty of WordPress plugins are messy; I completely agree with OP wanting to learn how to do it, and avoid bloated plugins.